# MongoDb Bulk update in batch mode c#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, c#-4.0

I am having lets say 10 collection in mongoDb and I have to update the collection's some field value everyday, each collection will be having minimum 70 Million's of records in it and when I am trying to update it from C# it was taking more than 2 hours for each collection.
From C# I am using Bulk Update and my mongo db version is 3.0.0.4 and C# driver is 2.0.

```
 var bulk = col.InitializeUnorderedBulkOperationAs<Employee>();
 bulk.Find(query).Update(update);
 var result = bulk.Execute();
```

Do we have any better way to update the collections in faster way?

Comment: Try remove database update logging module of MondoDB. I think this will decrease query execution time. And once look at query execution plan and put indexes to speed up search.

Comment: Yes all the search fields are indexed...

Comment: did u try by removing mongodb logging?

Comment: @user1941 you mean to say to remove the logging in server configuration settings?

Comment: but not to remove completely, try to dont log for every operation. I

Comment: http://codeandcodes.com/2014/07/31/mongodb-performance-enhancements-and-tweaks/

Comment: check the last point. I think it is suitable.